# Mockito "cannot select from parameterized type" issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock for testing purpose:

ClassA classA = Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);

Mockito.when(classA.void(Mockito.any(ClassB<String, ClassC>.class), Mockito.any(ClassD.class))).thenReturn("passed");

but I have info on "ClassB<String, ClassC>":
cannot select from  parameterized type.

ClassA void:
ClassA.void(@NotNull ClassB<String, ClassC> classB, ClassD classD){...}

mockito-core-4.0.0, springboot, maven

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Will you please let know if ClassA is a Bean or not? Also you need to change this 'ClassB<String, ClassC>.class' **with** ClassB.class.

Comment: ClassA is a Bean (@Component)
Also you need to change this 'ClassB<String, ClassC>.class' with ClassB.class - after change there is info:
Required Type: T
Provided:          void
Reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exists so that void conforms to T

Answer (score 0):

Okay,Here is what you need to do in Order to Solve your problem.

First replace this line:`ClassA classA = Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);` With

```
@MockBean
private Class classA;
```

As a class level variable.
After that you need to change your following piece of code:

```
ClassB<String, ClassC>.class
```

To

```
ClassB<Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(ClassC.class)>.class
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem. Please accept if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a "void" that returns nothing, it is impossible for it to return a String value. Solution is:
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception("Error occurred")).when(classA).void(Mockito.any(ClassB.class), Mockito.any(ClassD.class)); and then
classA.void(Mockito.any(ClassB.class), Mockito.any(ClassD.class));
.....
'voidName' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!
Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
If you need to set the void method to do nothing you can use:
doNothing().when(mock).someVoidMethod();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).